# OAuth2 still asking for email & password values

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm moving my AdWords app from Client Login to OAuth2 authentication in preparation to migrate to v201306.

I've read the documentation and understand the concept of OAuth2 and have experimented successfully with a little Google+ login script.

I'm confused about how my app will use OAuth2 instead of Client Login.

In auth.ini I've replaced the Client Login's email and password with OAuth2's client_id and client_secret from the api console but I immediately receive a validation error asking for email and password values.

I was under the impression that the existence of client_id and client_secret would prompt the use of OAuth2 ?

As always any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using library: adwords_api_php_4.2.5 version: v201302

Many thanks

Comment: Ewan Hemming has put together a useful tutorial about using the Google OAuth2 playground to access API Tokens: http://www.ewanheming.com/adwords-api-oauth-playground

Comment: Also, a thread on the Google developer forum explains the process I went through myself: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/community/?place=msg%2Fadwords-api%2FSug3QJdzorQ%2F7FJW5qHbaq8J